# How do I check to see if a row contains a 1 at a specific column name using python with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, loops, computer-science

I want to print out C and C1 along with other row names that have 1 in the braf column. So I want my output to be C, C1,...

```
      'Braf'
'C'      1     
'NC'     0
'C1'     1
...      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If need index values if match column `Braf` use:

```
m = df['Braf'] == 1
groupA, groupbB = df.index[m].tolist(), df.index[~m].tolist()
```

If need get values of column `0`:

```
m = df['Braf'] == 1
groupA, groupbB = df.loc[m, 0].tolist(), df.loc[~m, 0].tolist()
```

If need extract values by first column:

```
m = (df['Braf'] == 1).to_numpy()
groupA, groupbB = df.iloc[m, 0].tolist(), df.iloc[~m, 0].tolist()
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a','b','c'],
                   'Braf':[1,0, 1]}, index=['C','NC','C1'])
print (df)
   col  Braf
C    a     1
NC   b     0
C1   c     1

#labels of indices
print (df.index)
Index(['C', 'NC', 'C1'], dtype='object')

#first column - selected by position - labels are same
print (df.iloc[:, 0])
C     a
NC    b
C1    c
Name: col, dtype: object

#column Braf - labels are same
print (df['Braf'])
C     1
NC    0
C1    1
Name: Braf, dtype: int64
```

Comment: So does the loop you have check each row at that certain column name. I want to see if e every row contains a 1 at the column that is named Braf

Comment: @Bubbelz - `So does the loop you have check each row at that certain column name` - no, you loop by columns names.

Comment: @Bubbelz - Hard to understand what need, do you need test all columns without first column for 1? It seems your solution do (if some errors are removed). If need test column `Braf`, added `EDIT` part to my answer. But hard to know it it is what need, because no sample data (3 columns, 5 rows) and exepcted ouput in question

Comment: So basically I want to output all the row names that have a 1 in a column named BRAF does clear it up?

Comment: @Bubbelz - So `out = df.index[df['Braf'] == 1].tolist()` ?

Comment: @Bubbelz = Added code for both lists, for not matched values invert masl by `~`.

Comment: one more question what would I add to out = df.index[df['Braf'] == 1].tolist() to print the name of those rows which are located in column 0 Index outputs the location of those rows

Comment: @Bubbelz SO need extract values form column `0` ? `print (df[0])` ?

Comment: so that is used to print all values in column 0 how would you do for example Col[0]row[1]

Comment: @Bubbelz - OK, so first is necessary forget for loops. So What need? `groupA, groupbB = df.loc[m, 0].tolist(), df.loc[~m, 0].tolist()` working if exist column `0`? Because hard to know what need without data

Comment: @Bubbelz - added solution for extract values by first column

Comment: I updated the question to show what the excel sheet looks like there are more values but that is an example of what im trying to do

Comment: @Bubbelz - hmmm, so my first solution do it, what is problem with it?

Comment: Is there a way to print the names of the rows e.g C1 instead of the indexes because the indexes print out the indexes of the rows.

Comment: @Bubbelz - `names of the rows` is same like `indexes`.

Comment: @Bubbelz - added sample data to answer for see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the indices of rows with a specific value in a specific column you can use `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BRAF': [0,1,0,1,1]})

d = df.index.groupby(df['BRAF'].eq(1))
# you can also directly use 0/1 if binary

groupA = d[True]
# [0, 2]
groupB = d[False]
# [1, 3, 4]
```

Or directly as dictionary:

```
out = df.index.groupby(np.where(df['BRAF'].eq(1), 'groupA', 'groupB'))
```

Output:

```
{'groupA': [1, 3, 4],
 'groupB': [0, 2]}
```